# ignoring existing dialyzer errors with make and grep

Tags: jenkins, grep, erlang, makefile, dialyzer

I am trying to get jenkins to run dialyzer on erlang code but I am having a problem. As we are introducing this into an existing project there are a number of existing errors that we don't want to flag, which we have in the file *dialyzer-ignore-warnings*

I have this in my makefile, but what I really want it to do is to return 0 if the grep returns an empty document and a value if there are new errors. But my script-fu is just not up to it

```
(DEPS_PLT): compile
    @echo Building local plt at $(DEPS_PLT)
    @echo 
    @(echo "Using Dialyzer in `which dialyzer`"; dialyzer --output_plt $(DEPS_PLT) --build_plt --apps  $(DEPS))


dialyzer: compile $(DEPS_PLT)
    @(echo "Using Dialyzer in `which dialyzer`"; dialyzer --fullpath --plt $(DEPS_PLT) -Wrace_conditions -r ./ebin)|\
    fgrep -v -f ./dialyzer-ignore-warnings
```

Comment: `grep` returns zero if any lines are printed out and non-zero if no lines are printed out. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
dialyzer: compile $(DEPS_PLT)
    @echo "Using Dialyzer in `which dialyzer`"
    @(dialyzer --fullpath --plt $(DEPS_PLT) -Wrace_conditions -r ./ebin)|\
    fgrep -v -f ./dialyzer-ignore-warnings; test "$$?" != 0
```

That is, ensure that the exit code from `fgrep` is *not* zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar solution from [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar)'s repository:

[Makefile](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/cd55176009df794f506771fd574de9303ff2a42e/Makefile) contains:

```
dialyzer: dialyzer_warnings
    @diff -U0 dialyzer_reference dialyzer_warnings

dialyzer_warnings:
    -@dialyzer -q -nn -n ebin -Wunmatched_returns -Werror_handling \
        -Wrace_conditions > dialyzer_warnings
```

[Reference file](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/cd55176009df794f506771fd574de9303ff2a42e/dialyzer_reference) contains:

```
rebar_eunit.erl:388: Call to missing or unexported function eunit_test:function_wrapper/2
rebar_utils.erl:163: Call to missing or unexported function escript:foldl/3
```